# When I run my project in Android Studio, adb emulator doesn't work

Tags: android

screen shot is below. The progress bar doesn't end. And emulator screen doesn't show me the screen of the smart phone.
I searched hard and I installed Intel x86 Atom sytsem image(?) on intel website
 And set my grphic setting to 'software' instead of 'hardware' or 'automatic', but it still didn't work. Please help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using haxm?

Comment: I don't know. Did i need that? I couldn't see any error message about that.

Comment: I just see endless progress bar with message 'Waiting for target device to come online'

Comment: haxm makes sure that its not running slowly. The android emulator can be extremely slow. Using haxm makes it run smooth.

Comment: It turned out Im using that.

Comment: But i cant find vt-x in my laptop's bios

Comment: But when i do haxm check, i get
VT support -- yes
NX support -- yes

Comment: finally I get to see 'android' logo on my simulator screen after i update haxm version. But it's freaking slow..

Comment: I solved it! Thank you

Comment: accept my answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install HAXM and make sure its updated.